# Help with vertically aligning enumerate labels

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I am just getting started using latex and am having some problem vertically aligning the enumerate labels when listing tables (see image below). I would like to have the '(a)' label aligned vertically with the table, rather than being centered vertically.

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item 
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
    & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    $ \times$ & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    & & & & & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & 0 & & \\
    + & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & & & \\
    \hline
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Use the optional argument to `tabular`: `\begin{tabular}[t]{...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `tabular` to indicate the vertical alignment; in your case, the `t` option is required:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c}
    & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    $ \times$ & & & & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \hline
    & & & & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    & & & & & & 0 & \\
    & & & & & 0 & & \\
    + & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & & & \\
    \hline
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```