# Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?

Tags: graphics, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28939/help-with-vertically-aligning-enumerate-labels) a while ago about vertically aligning enumerate labels to the top of table. Now I am having the same problem, but with images. Since my problem was solved in my previous thread, I tried sticking the image in a single-cell table and aligning that with the tabular's alignment parameter, but it seemed to have no effect.

Can someone explain what is the correct way to align this image and why didn't sticking it in a table work as expected? I am simply trying to align the enumerate label with the top of my image.

[image]

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item\begin{tabular}[t]{l}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{13a.png}\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Martin Scharrer's package [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) will help you:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
...
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item\adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{13a.png}}
\end{enumerate}
```

The image will be set so that its height will match that of words and it will stick below the baseline.

---

In case `adjustbox` is not available, one can do in a more complicated way; after loading the `calc` package

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

saying

```
\raisebox{-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{13a.png}}
```

will have the same effect.

Comment: With that I get this error: `|149 error| Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \relax  ...udegraphics[valign=t,width=10cm]{13a.png} `. Any ideas what that is about?

Comment: @nw. I changed the code

Comment: @nw.: This error got fixed with v0.8 of `adjustbox`. You can since use the following again: `\includegraphics[width=10cm,valign=t]{13a.png}`. Note that the order of the options influences the alignment. If `valign` is used first `width` will also scale the height and depth.

Comment: Is there a solution without a dependency on an external package? I can't install latex packages on my work computer.

Comment: @Turion I've added the code

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

Just saw this when looking for myself.  I found the easiest way to do this is:

```
item[a)] \text{}\\
\includegraphics{foo.bar}
```

No need for extra packages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: i think you want a backslash before `\item`, and you might also want to note that the packages `graphicx` and `amsmath` are needed.  otherwise, very nice.