# Figures in enumerate environment

Tags: graphics, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image)

I want to place the images I have in an `enumerate` environment, however when I try to do it, if there is not a text (or anything) above the image, it places the number at the end of the picture, not top of it. I already tried floating and non-floating methods to place the image but I couldn't do it. Many thanks to everyone who will try to help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Duplicate: [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image)