# How to put the labels of enumerated images at the middle left of the images?

Tags: graphics, lists, enumerate, multicol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image)

The current code produces the labels at the lower left corners of the enumerated images.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,multicol,enumerate}
\columnsep=5pt

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bf 1.]
\item Which is the correct diagram?
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[a.]
            \item \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}           
            \item \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
            \item \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-grid-100x100pt}            
            \item \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}           
            \item \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\item What is your name?
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

How to put the labels of enumerated images at the middle left of the images?

Comment: With the `adjustbox` package it's easy to position the image as one prefers. However, for languages written from left to right and from top to bottom, the order of the labels seems wrong: "a" and "b" should be in the first row. *Never* use `\bf`: `\bfseries` is the correct command.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for this useful comment. I have made the answer in wiki.

Comment: [Almost identical question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30367/19356).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,multicol,enumerate,adjustbox}
\columnsep=5pt
\def\importgraphics#1{\adjustbox{valign=m}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1.]
\item Which is the correct diagram?
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[a.]
            \item \importgraphics{example-image-A}
            \item \importgraphics{example-image-B}
            \item \importgraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}           
            \item \importgraphics{example-image-A}          
            \item \importgraphics{example-image-B}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
\item What is your name?
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```