# How do I have the list item appear on the top left of the image?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I am including an image with the [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package in an enumerated list.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\includegraphics[width=100px]{my_image.png}
\end{enumerate}
```

The list item number appears on the bottom left of the image. I tried to place the list item number above left of the image with a new line to no avail.

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\newline
\includegraphics[width=100px]{my_image.png}
\end{enumerate}
```

How do I place the list item number above left of the image?

Comment: have you seen [Aligning enumerate labels to top of image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30367) ? Let us know if this resolves it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As cmhughes suggested [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image)
should resolve your problem. 
You will have to install the following packages:`adjustbox` and `collectbox`.

A simple code that works is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Achieving lowest possible noise$\rightarrow$Iron-$55$ Spectrum
    \item \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{scope}
    \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{scope}}%This will work just the way you like it
    \item $Fe$ and $Ar:$$Ar$ signal is not clear...
    \item Just to check: move source from center
    \item Expected behaviour
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

Image is drawn with `tikZ`. Example taken from [TeXample.net](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/textronics-oscilloscope/)