# Enumerate a list of images [in Lyx]

Tags: graphics, lyx, enumerate

Here's the problem. The list counter appears at the bottom of the image.[image] 
I'm simply trying to enumerate a list of images, no text is involved in the list.

How do I fix this to appear at the top-left side of the image like it's supposed to?

Comment: Thanks! Well I just answered my own question - I need to get a life. xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a clean, LyX-like approach, add

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

to your preamble, and then insert the image with the LaTeX and LyX options `valign=t`:

[image]

The above approach avoids you having to use ERTs which may impede readability. While the input may show a different vertical alignment

[image]

the output provides the desired display

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The question was answered twice before [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97801/how-do-i-have-the-list-item-appear-on-the-top-left-of-the-image?rq=1) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/aligning-enumerate-labels-to-top-of-image), but both times for latex. So I'm just writing the lyx edition.

I added `\usepackage{adjustbox}`to my preamble

and wrote (using the ERT) `\adjustbox{valign=t}{`before the image then a `}` after it to close the code. 
[image]

And it got me this result.
[image]