# Shifting a tabular environment down in an enumerate environment

Tags: tables, enumerate

I've seen several related questions on this website, but nothing for my particular problem. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\setlength\itemindent{0in}
\item $i = 0.06$
\item \begin{tabular}[h]{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{First Year} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Renewal Years} \\
 \hline
 & Percent of & Per & Percent of & Per \\
 & Premium & Policy & Premium & Policy \\
 \hline
 Taxes & 4\% & 0 & 4\% & 0 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need this to look something like (modified using Paint):

[image]

`\vspace{some length}` has not worked after `\item`, as this shifts the `\item` as well. I have also tried using `vspace` and enclosing the `tabular` environment with `{}`; it gives the same effect which I don't want.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Help with vertically aligning enumerate labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28939/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raise it into position after setting it to be `[t]`op-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemindent=0pt]
  \item $i = 0.06$
  \item \raisebox{\ht\strutbox}{\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{First Year} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Renewal Years} \\
    \hline
    & Percent of & Per & Percent of & Per \\
    & Premium & Policy & Premium & Policy \\
    \hline
    Taxes & 4\% & 0 & 4\% & 0 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The option `h` is not valid for `tabular`; it should be either `t` or `b`, meaning top or bottom alignment (default is vertical centering).

However, the initial rule will produce an unwanted result; it's sufficient to load `array` and change the first `\hline` into `\firsthline`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemindent=0pt]
\item $i = 0.06$
\item \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\firsthline
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{First Year} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Renewal Years} \\
 \hline
 & Percent of & Per & Percent of & Per \\
 & Premium & Policy & Premium & Policy \\
 \hline
 Taxes & 4\% & 0 & 4\% & 0 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note that `itemindent=0pt` is better placed in the options to `enumerate`, rather than set later with `\setlength`.

[image]