# Item letter and table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate

How do I put the lettered item on the same row as the first row of the table? I tried to modify the placement of the \ item, but was unsuccessful. :(

As it is in the document:

[image]

How it should be:

[image]

Table Code:

```
\item  \begin{tabular}{lll}
                        (1)\, $2x + 3y = 24 $ \\
                        (2)\, $(x = 6 \to y = 4) \vee 2x = 12$\\ 
                        (3)\, $(2x = 12 \to x = 6) \vee 2x + 3y \neq 24 $ \\
                        (4)\, $x \neq 6 $ \\
                        \hline
                        $\;\therefore \;\;  2x = 12 \to y = 4 $\\\\
                \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put the fragment into a compilable minimal document that people can play with.

Comment: But you can add `[t]` to align the tabular. `\begin{tabular}[t]{l}`. Why do you need three columns if you're only using one?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you explain the meaning of "t"?

Comment: It places the reference point of the box created by `tabular` according to its top line. You can have `t`(op), `c`(enter) and `b`(ottom).

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [Help with vertically aligning enumerate labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28939/134144)

Comment: @leandriis You must be an archivist or librarian of some sort. :-) Your link appears to be relevant, however I find this question a bit clearer (the screenshots speak for themselves).